# Не запускаются sh скрипты в Докер контейнере. exec sh: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, sh

имеется докер файл

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

....

COPY _docker/app/run.sh /home/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/run.sh"]
WORKDIR /var/www
```

файл run.sh лежит в каталоге _docker/app/
его код

```
#!/bin/bash
# Start PHP-FPM
php-fpm -D
cd /var/www
composer install
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate
if [ -f "/var/www/vendor/workerman/_var_www_WS.php.pid" ]; then
    rm -f /var/www/vendor/workerman/_var_www_WS.php.pid
fi
php /var/www/WS.php start
```

если запустить сборку проекта, то данный контейнер упадет с ошибкой
`exec /home/run.sh: no such file or directory`

если закомментировать ENTRYPOINT в докерфайле, то все будет работать, но при попытке запустить этот же скрипт из контейнера будет такая же ошибка.
если проверить в контейнере есть ли этот файл, то он есть и открывается.
как его запустить? желательно при сборке контейнера.

Comment: Ошибку выдает скрипт, в скрипте вижу две возможные отсылки к указанной ошибке: `cd /var/www` и `php /var/www/WS.php start`. Проверьте что папка /var/www и файл /var/www/WS.php существуют.

Comment: все файлы на месте.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился следующим путем:
Отключил ENTRYPOINT в Dockerfile, закомментировал все строки в run.sh, В run.sh добавил строку `echo "hello"`
запустил контейнер, запустил скрипт - все отработало в консоле все вывелось.
Затем раскомментировал по 1 строке файл run.sh  и пересобирал контейнер.
После это расскоментировал ENTRYPOINT, все запустилось.
запушил в гит, удалил все контейнеры и имейджи, клонировал проект в другую папку, запустил сборку и все заработало с 1 раза.
Что было я так и не понял. Но сборка теперь собирается на других устройствах и разных ОС